# How to add multiple ports in Helm service template?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

How can I make below snippet to support multiple ports? The template should print multiple individual port sections.

The template I currently have is:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "myapp.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "myapp.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      targetPort: {{ .Values.service.targetPort }}
      protocol: UDP
      name: port1
  selector:
    {{- include "myapp.selectorLabels" . | nindent 4 }}
```

The expected output in the service spec should look like:

```yaml
ports:
-  name: ex1
   port: 100
   protocol: TCP
   targetPort: 80
-  name: ex2
   port: 101
   protocol: TCP
   targetPort: 8080
-  name: ex3
   port: 103
   protocol: TCP
   targetPort: 5555
```

Comment: You should be able to just include multiple entries under `ports:` in your template.  There's no specific requirement that they be tied back to a single `service:` item in the Helm values.  What have you already tried, and what problems are you running into?

Answer (score 4):

Helm has [flow control](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/). The `range` keyword provides a "for each"-style loop.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "myapp.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "myapp.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
    {{- range .Values.ports }}
    - port: {{ .port }}
      targetPort: {{ .targetPort }}
      protocol: {{ .protocol }}
      name: {{ .name }}
    {{- end }}
  selector:
    {{- include "myapp.selectorLabels" . | nindent 4 }}
```